HTTP download shows a marquee instead of a progress bar
This is part of a perl script used for years for downloading files via http. Now it still download the files, but it seems the Content-length field cannot be readed by the http client (chrome, edge or firefox tested); so the progress bars are doing a marquee instead of a progress.
$file = "$ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT}$dir/$arch";
$len = -s $file;
print "Content-Type:application/octet-stream\n";
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$arch\n";
print "Content-Length:$len\n\n";
open FILE, "< $file" or Error('Cannot read '.$arch);
binmode FILE;
local $/ = \32768;
while (<FILE>){
    print $_;
};
close FILE;

Somebody know why this behaviour changed?

$arch must be ASCII or encoded. A larger buffer might speed up things, maybe the for me unknown \32768 which seems 16K but I read as illegal octal number, but Perl...

@Joop Eggen It's a reference to a scalar containing 32k. When $/ is a reference to a number, it's taken a block size. (Assigning 32768 would read lines terminated by the 5 byte sequence 32768.)

Use your browser's debugging tools (F12 in FF and Chrome) to obtain the response. What do you get?

Are you sure its a changed browser behavior causing the issue? I assume that this is part of a CGI script run from inside a web server, so maybe the server behavior has changed. See for example Browsers not recognising Content-Length header when using apache and cgi

Show an actual response so we can see what the client sees.

@Steffen Ullrich, Re "Are you sure its a changed browser behavior causing the issue?", Noone said the browser caused the issue. The OP said the issue caused a change in the browser.

We see something is changing our headers; debugging the response we see the content-length is not present in the header, but there is a "Transfer-Encoding =chunked". Is it possible that the appache server is doing that?

Not an answer, but just a guess unless it gets a green tick by the original poster:
The context I assume is that we are talking about a legacy CGI Perl script .  It is used for downloading platform-specific files ($arch) that are potentially huge.
If the size of these files exceed 2 GiB (or is it 4 GiB?, sorry, I cannot check right now), the Content-Length header reported via the $len variable may have a negative value because of a number overflow.  I am guessing again that user agents may ignore negative Content-Length headers, and that is why the original poster is seeing a marquee instead of a percentual progress indication in their user agent.
Off-topic: Do you verify that $dir and $arch match your expectations, especially that they do not contain any sequences of ../? Otherwise, the marquee is not your problem. You should rather be concerned that people can download arbitrary files from your web server by tinkering the URL parameters.

Thank you. The bigger file we are downloading with this perl scrit is always lower than 35 megabytes in size. And we are sure the $dir and $arch are right, because the files are always downloaded properly. –
